# How to know when your GUI is ready XCode / Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

How do I know when my GUI is ready, so I can initialize my GUI components?
I want to retrieve HTML from a server (don't know how, so you may see a post from me concerning that) and put that in a text field (maybe UIWebView), but how do I know when the UI is ready?
I don't want a big button with the text "RETRIEVE DATA" or something like that.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- (void) awakeFromNib` is what you are looking for.
Of course you want to do somethings in `viewdidload` as well.

From the Apple docs:

> An awakeFromNib message is sent to each object loaded from the archive, but only if it can respond to the message, and only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet instance variables set.

if you don't use a xib file definitely you want to use `viewdidload`:

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

Comment: Can somebody give me an example? I'm just beginning with Objective-C. So do I have to override that method? Where? Or do I have to extend NSView or something and override that method?

Comment: I imagine you have a xib file and a pair of viewcontroller .m and .h files, in your .m file (your UIviewcontroller subclass) you want to override either of the two methods mentioned. Post your code for people to comment on if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks! So I;m doing it all wrong by dragging UI-components to a main-window in Interface-Builder and creating a Listenerclass for button-clicks and so on. So I have to subclass UIViewController? What do I have to do with that subclass, add it to my main window?

Comment: I told you, I was just beginning :P

Comment: Oh my goodness, may I suggest watching the first few sessions of the Stanford's iOS programming course on iTunesU, that gets you started in no time, I highly recommend it. If you insist, we can proceed here, then! :) tell me if you need to link to the course.

Comment: This is the link, I highly recommend it, http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

Comment: Sorry this is the link, that one is for the more advanced course, check this one out. http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774

Comment: Thanks for the vids, they're are really interesting, but they focus on iOS, and I am trying to develop something for an iMac, not an iPhone. Does that matter? @Ali

Comment: It matters a bit! they share a lot, so this is how it is done, you need if you have a NSViewController subclass (just "add new file" and select NSViewController). there I believe you get stubs for all the functions you need to override.

Comment: Thank you for the vids again, I now watched the first one and, although he did no coding, I can now see, that what I was doing was entirely wrong!

Comment: The principles are more or less the same between iOS and MacOS, and they share lots of frameworks and more importantly they share the design philosophy.

Comment: How can I get a MVC-template for MAC OS X, so the the 'File's Owner' is my controller, and it creates all those files for me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9658/discussion-between-ali-and-11684)

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)viewDidLoad` is the method to perform all the task.. (this is in every viewcontroller..) you should refer this **[view controller life cycle by apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW1)**... it wil help ou conceptualize what you need.. (must for eevry iPhone programmer)

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is usually composed of one or more views that are managed by a view controller that you customize.  The view controller can implement a variety of callback methods that tell it when the views have been loaded, when they're about to appear, when they have appeared....